# Compute real size of svg considering stroke and transformations

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an svg element and I need to compute the real size of the element.

For example consider this:

```
<g>
   <path d="M 0 0 L 20 0" symbol-local-id="42a57c74-adcf-480a-b193-572a1c50a7a1" fill="none" stroke="#666666" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="flat" pointer-events="all"/>
</g>
```

The expected size should be **width:20px** and **height:3px**

The SVG can be much more complicated than this, so I need to compute it dynamically.

I can't use getBBox() nor getBoundingClientRect() because they compute size without considering stroke.

So I tried to render it in a canvas and count the number of pixels to get the real size, but things don't work I continue to get height 1px.

This is the algorithm to compute the size:

```
const rasterSVGAndGetRealSize = function (svgEl, renderedCallback) {

    svgEl.removeAttribute('viewBox');
    svgEl.removeAttribute('width');
    svgEl.removeAttribute('height');
    svgEl.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';

    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = 'path, text, rect, ellipse { fill: rgba(0,0,0,1) !important; stroke: rgba(0,0,0,1)!important}';
    svgEl.insertBefore(style, svgEl.firstChild);

    const serialized = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgEl);
    const uri = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(serialized);

    // load svg image into canvas
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const w = image.naturalWidth;
        const h = image.naturalHeight;
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
        const data = imageData.data;
        let left = w;
        let top = h;
        let right = 0;
        let bottom = 0;
        for (let r = 0; r < h; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < w; c++) {
                const pixel = w * r + c;
                const red = data[4 * pixel];
                const green = data[4 * pixel + 1];
                const blue = data[4 * pixel + 2];
                const alpha = data[4 * pixel + 3];
                if (red !== 255 || green !== 255 || blue !== 255) {
                    if (c < left) {
                        left = c;
                    }
                    if (r < top) {
                        top = r;
                    }
                    if (c > right) {
                        right = c;
                    }
                    if (r > bottom) {
                        bottom = r;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        renderedCallback({ left: left, top: top, right: right, bottom: bottom, width: right - left + 1, height: bottom - top + 1 });
        //canvas.setAttribute('id', 'imageTest');
        //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    image.src = uri;
};
```

What is wrong? Do you know another solution to compute the real size of the SVG?

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/orbintsoft/jo17fkgr/5/

Comment: getBoundingClientRect considers the stroke in Firefox at least. We raised a spec issue but I'm not sure if anything changed spec wise.

Comment: That works only in Firefox so I can't use. The spec says to pass an options parameter to getBBox, but currently no brower supports it yet, So I am trying to compute it manually.
I think the problem in my algorithm is that part of stroke is outside of canvas, I need to set a negative viewBox but I can't estimate the offset without knowing the size

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found is to overestimate the size of the SVG, and translate all elements inside.
Another important thing is to disable antialiasing with crispedges.
To avoid problems with null pixel and unwanted antialiased pixels, I set 2 very distant colors, but different from black and white.

Here my solution:

```
(function(global) {
    global.ComputeBoundingBox = {
        rasterSVGAndGetRealBoundingBox : function (svgEl, overEstimatedWidth, overEstimatedHeight, leftOffset = 50, topOffset = 50) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                let svgRoot = null;
                if (svgEl.tagName === 'svg') {
                    svgRoot = svgEl;
                } else {
                    svgRoot = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
                    svgRoot.appendChild(svgEl);
                }
                svgRoot.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${overEstimatedWidth} ${overEstimatedHeight}`);
                svgRoot.removeAttribute('width', `${overEstimatedWidth}px`);
                svgRoot.removeAttribute('height', `${overEstimatedHeight}px`);
                svgRoot.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(240,240,240, 1)';

                const style = document.createElement('style');
                style.innerHTML = 'path, text, rect, ellipse { fill: rgba(10,10,10,1) !important; stroke: rgba(10,10,10,1)!important; shape-rendering: crispEdges !important; }';
                svgRoot.insertBefore(style, svgRoot.firstChild);

                for (let el of svgRoot.childNodes) {
                    if (el.tagName === 'g' || el.tagName === 'rect' || el.tagName === 'path' || el.tagName === 'text' || el.tagName === 'ellipse' || el.tagName === 'circle' || el.tagName === 'line' || el.tagName === 'polyline' || el.tagName === 'polygon') {
                        const cloned = el.cloneNode(true);
                        const g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
                        g.appendChild(cloned);
                        el.replaceWith(g);
                        g.style.transform = `translate(${leftOffset}px, ${topOffset}px)`;
                        g.style.transformOrigin = 'center';
                        g.style.transformBox = 'fillBox';
                    }
                }


                const serialized = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgRoot);
                const uri = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(serialized);
                // load svg image into canvas
                const image = new Image();
                image.onload = function () {
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    let w = overEstimatedWidth;
                    let h = overEstimatedHeight;
                    canvas.width = w;
                    canvas.height = h;
                    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
                    const data = imageData.data;
                    let left = w;
                    let top = h;
                    let right = 0;
                    let bottom = 0;
                    for (let r = 0; r < h; r++) {
                        for (let c = 0; c < w; c++) {
                            const pixel = w * r + c;
                            const red = data[4 * pixel];
                            const green = data[4 * pixel + 1];
                            const blue = data[4 * pixel + 2];
                            const alpha = data[4 * pixel + 3];
                            if ((red === 10) || (green === 10) || (blue === 10)) {
                                if (c < left) {
                                    left = c;
                                }
                                if (r < top) {
                                    top = r;
                                }
                                if (c > right) {
                                    right = c;
                                }
                                if (r > bottom) {
                                    bottom = r;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    left -= leftOffset;
                    right = right - leftOffset + 1;
                    top -= topOffset;
                    bottom = bottom - topOffset + 1;
                    resolve({ left: left, top: top, right: right, bottom: bottom, width: right - left, height: bottom - top });
                }
                image.src = uri;
            });
        }
    }
})(window);



const svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g><path d="M 0 0 L 20 0" fill="none" stroke="#666666" stroke-width="3"/></g></svg>';

const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(svg,"image/svg+xml");
const root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

const promise = ComputeBoundingBox.rasterSVGAndGetRealBoundingBox(root, 1000, 1000);
promise.then((size) => {console.dir(size);});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/54yvjhwt/1/

Since this solution involves many contraints, I hope someone will be able to improve and provide a better solution.